# Conditional on parameter

Tags: powershell

I'm gathering users from Azure, via `az` module, and would like to write a condition based on the chosen output type. If the user outputs as .csv, it will convert the data from json and export-csv. If they output on any other type, it just does Out-File. The problem is it just skips over the check for if it's a csv or not.

```
function Get-AzureUsers 
{

    [CmdletBinding()]
     Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][String]$OutFile = $null)    

    $split = $OutFile.Split(".")
    $type = $split[1]
    $name = $split[0]
    If($type -eq "csv")
    {
        $i=az ad user list -o json | ConvertFrom-Json
        $i | export-csv $OutFile
    } 
    else
    {
        If($Outfile)
        {
         $i=az ad user list -o table | Out-File $OutFile
        }
        else 
        {
        #az ad user list -o yaml
        }

}
```

Comment: Did you try putting any breakpoint to see what was going on ? I called your function `Get-AzureUsers -OutFile 'c:\test.csv'` and it got into your condition. Is there any dot in the path you are saving too ? This could be problematic with your current implementation. Use `$type = $split[-1]` to ensure it always take the extension (since $split[1] won't work if the path is :c:\My.Folder\test.csv)

Comment: Ah that was it, it was running in a directory with a space in it. Thank you!